# Moving AEM Touch UI pages based on path on page properties

Tags: javascript, aem

We are given a requirement such that the page should be moved to a location based on the path provided at the page properties.

How to implement that in Touch UI?
In Classic UI we can use edit config and may use listeners and write respective JS code on that.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Do you want to actually move the node in the JCR upon saving the dialog or do you want to use a Vanity URL?

Comment: @nateyolles yes I want the node to be actually moved.

Comment: Can you not use AEM's move feature ?

Comment: @Abhishek No.The customer wants this functionality in the page properties tab only.

Answer (score 1):

Your question alludes to wanting to use JavaScript to move the page. I've put together an example using the Touch UI dialog. It works, but would require polish to validate user input and prevent string manipulation errors.

In this example, I'm using the `dialog-success` event that triggers after a dialog is saved. See [Touch UI Events](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-events.html). I check to see if the textfield with the CSS selector is populated, and if it is, I post back to the Sling Post Servlet using the [@MoveFrom suffix](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#movefrom) to move the node and its children (the page and the jcr:content, etc...). If that operation is successful, navigate the user to the new page.

In your dialog, add a textfield and give it a unique class name:

```
<movePage
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
    fieldLabel="Move page to:"
    class="move-page"/>
```

Then add this JavaScript to a ClientLib used only in authoring mode such as `cq.authoring.editor`:

```
(function ($, $document) {
    'use strict';

    $document.on("dialog-success", function(e) {
        var newPath,
            lastSlash,
            moveFromSuffix,
            newDirectory,
            currentPath,
            data;

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        newPath = $('.move-page').val();

        if (newPath) {
            lastSlash = newPath.lastIndexOf('/');
            moveFromSuffix = newPath.substring(lastSlash + 1) + Granite.Sling.MOVE_SUFFIX;
            newDirectory = newPath.substring(0, lastSlash);
            currentPath = Granite.HTTP.getPath().replace('/editor.html', '');
            data = {};
            data[moveFromSuffix] = currentPath;

          $.post(newDirectory, data)
              .done(function(){
                  window.location = '/editor.html' + newPath + '.html';
              })
              .fail(function(){
                  $(window).adaptTo('foundation-ui').alert('Alert', 'Could not move page');
              });
        }
    });
})($, $(document));
```

However, another option would be to do it server side by implementing a custom [Sling Post Processor](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling8/org/apache/sling/servlets/post/class-use/SlingPostProcessor.html).

Comment: As mentioned I need to retrieve "path to move" from page properties. In order to apply the above mentioned JS in page properties dialog where should I include this clientlib? I tried including the clientlib in the page but as we know dialog is not a part of page but it is in sites console how can I include JS in sites console

Comment: Create a clientlib as you normally would. For example, create a folder such as `/etc/designs/mysite/clientlib-author` of `jcr:primaryType` `cq:ClientLibraryFolder` with a `categories` property type `String[]` and value of `cq.authoring.editor`. Add this JS in a file named `page.js`. Add a filed called `js.txt` with a single line: `page.js`. When you navigate to localhost:4502/editor.html/content/mysite/mypage.html, this JavaScript will be available. When you navigate to the page outside of the touch UI editor mode, the script will not be available.

Comment: yes.but I need to include this in page properties dialog. The page properties dialog is not a part of the page.It gets opened in sites console.Hence where should I add this script?

Comment: If you use the `granite.ui.foundation` category for your clientlib, your JavaScript will work in the page properties dialogs in `/sites.html`.

Comment: In the example above, I based the logic off the content author using editing from the page directly. However, you can update that logic to handle the sites console and your specific business requirements. The key is to post back to Sling using the @MoveFrom SlingPostServlet Suffix and then redirect the user because the resource they're editing is no longer at the location their browser is at.